# How to aggregate text in pandas according to another column name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to aggregate the text column of all the identical names. e.g.

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 'good', 3],
                   ['Jack', 'bad', 6],
                   ['Tom', 'average', 9],
                   ],
                  columns=['name', 'text', 'day'])
```

I want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 'good average'],
                   ['Jack', 'bad',],
                   ],
                  columns=['name', 'text'])
```

Comment: Try : ``df.groupby("name", sort=False, as_index = False).agg(text=("text", " ".join))``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby(by='name').agg(text=("text", lambda x: ",".join(set(x))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by an join

`df.groupby('name').agg({'text': ' '.join}, as_index=False)`

```
              text
name
Jack           bad
Tom   good average
```